# weird "count property undefined"

Tags: discord.js

I need help with this, honestly, I've given up on this, 'cause it should work. I don't know if it's a discord.js bug or something but I couldn't find where the issue is.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const live = "";
const rmke = "";

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
  let msg = await message.channel.send("Vote! LIVE  RMK ");

  await msg.react(live);
  await msg.react(rmke);

  const reactions = await msg.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === live || reaction.emoji.name === rmke, {
    time: 15000
  });
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Ready")
    .setDescription("Results")
    .addField("LIVE!", `${live}: ${reactions.get(live).count -1 }`)
    .addField("RMK!", `${rmke}: ${reactions.get(rmke).count -1 }`);
  message.channel.send({
    embed: embed
  });
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "vta"
}
```

```
(node:8592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\user\Documents\Mod9z\commands\vota.js:16:60)
(node:8592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8592) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nobody reacts `reactions.get(live)` and `reactions.get(rmke)` will be undefined because your bot reacts before the `awaitReactions` and so that one won't be counted.

The easiest way to deal with this would be:

```js
reactions.get(live) ? reactions.get(live).count : 0
```